# Is it possible to configure SPF / DKIM for @gmail.com email (not Google Workspace)?

Tags: gmail, spf, dkim

I use Google Apps Script to send emails, sometimes from @gmail.com addresses. Those emails are very frequently going to the SPAM folder.

I understand it's possible to set up SPF and DKIM in my domain's DNS settings. Is it possible to do something like that for these @gmail.com emails?

Comment: Do you really think Google would allow you or anyone else to modify their DNS settings? How would Google police perhaps millions of DNS changes? Think of the abuse that this would foster.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

This is because you don't manage `gmail.com`. If you want to implement SPF/DKIM/DMARC you should get a domain of your own and specify the settings there.

Regarding the first sentence: if your email is sent to spam, then investigate why that is. Or, better yet, send the email authenticated rather than anonymously. Yes, making an assumption here.

Comment: That's helpful. 

What does it mean to send the email "authenticated?"

Comment: You can send email either authenticated or unauthenticated. It seems, though that the MailApp API does not support authenticated email. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app I think your best bet is using the GMailApp API in this case. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)